# Linux find misses targets?

Tags: linux, find, command

I have a file structure as follows:

```
.
├── a.o
└── test_sub
    └── b.o
```

From test_sub, "find .. -name *.o" only produces b.o. Anything wrong?

```
$ find .. -name *.o
../test_sub/b.o
```

I am testing on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM if that matters.

Comment: When you say "From test_sub" are you trying to get find to look from the folder above to include a.o as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *.o wildcard in your cmd is interpreted by the shell, not by the find program. So, when your cwd is test_sub, the actual command executed is 'find .. -name b.o', which, correctly, finds b.o in ../test_sub.

What you actually want is that the *.o pattern is interpreted by the find command. So, you want to escape it, so that the shell leaves it alone:

$ find .. -name "*.o"